# mysql configuration for kafka web console

Tags: mysql, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

working on web console configuration for kafka which internally uses play framework. I am trying to use mysql configuration with below library
https://github.com/claudemamo/kafka-web-console

But this library is expecting zookeepers table in mysql database(checked with default h2 database also). 
I didn't find any documentation regarding database/table creation in library documentation. 
Do i need to create this table or need to find default zookeepers table for zookeeper service and configure to that.?

Comment: Consider using netflix's [exhibitor](https://github.com/Netflix/exhibitor) to view metrics/meta information on the Zookeeper process used by Kafka. It's a much better tool

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Zookeepers table in addition to a few other tables (e.g., status). However, Play! can take care of that. Launch the console and access the application page. Play! will ask you if you want to apply a no. of evolutions. Give it permission so that it can create the necessary tables. Make sure you change conf/application.conf so that the console connects to your MySql database.